# Is there a paste function in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, copy-paste

Chrome provides a `copy(myCopyObj)` to copy an object. Do we have anything similar in terms of pasting an object or getting the contents from the clipboard?

Comment: Use window.getSelection

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi

Comment: I am talking about chrome console NOT javascript or DOM for clipboard events.

Answer (score 3):

**"Getting the contents from clipboard"**

Execute the following on devtools side and within 3 seconds focus on the window (by clicking somewhere, or just hitting `<tab>`).

```
setTimeout(async()=>console.log(await window.navigator.clipboard.readText()), 3000)
```

This will just print the clipboard content. You can replace console.log with code that actually uses the clipboard content.

Answer (score 1):

Press enter after `copy(myCopyObj)` then try to Paste`(ctrl+V)`. This will solve your purpose.

Comment: I think the question is about accessing the clipboard content directly as a programmatic expression, like how `copy` takes an expression and sets the clipboard. You can use `ctrl+v` to paste the value into a string literal. But this is inconvenient if the clipboard is a string that contains newlines, which will need to be escaped from the string literal, or if it is an image or something else.